# Sinatra and Slim with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby

What do sidekiq do with slim and sinatra gems for monitoring, what does sinatra do and what does slim do?
And why do we set `require: false` with sinatra gem.

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq hasn't used slim for two years now.  You don't need it.

Sinatra is used to provide the Web UI.  `require: false` ensures it is not loaded where it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq uses slim and sinatra for its admin web page (where you can monitor your queue size, various counters, stuff like this)